# Graph theory and Burnside's lemma

Tags: graph-theory

> How many are non isomorphic tournaments (directed clique) with $n=5$ vertices?

I'm not sure how to understand isomorphism here. This problem was in the set of problems on Burnside's lemma but it's different than the rest, I think. Normally I was asked to count the number of significantly different colorings of necklace or chessboard which was very nice and the group for Burnside's lemma was given explicit - simply all rotations. But here I don't know what is the group, how to approach this.

Is it very difficult to solve this in general - for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Will it be useful here the term: graph automorphism? How to understand it? Because I have it in the next problem.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the question, a lot of the confusion is converting from group actions terminology to graph theory terminology.  I'll try to clarify.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of labelled [tournaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament) on the vertex set $\{1,2,\ldots,5\}$.  We know $$|\mathcal{A}|=2^{{5 \choose 2}}=1024$$ since each edge can go in one of two directions.  The [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_5$ [acts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on $\mathcal{A}$ by permuting the vertex labels.

Pick an arbitrary tournament $T \in \mathcal{A}$ and an arbitrary permutation $\alpha \in S_5$.

- We say that $T$ and $\alpha(T)$ are *isomorphic* (which we intuitively interpret as meaning structurally equivalent).
- We can define an equivalence relation on the set of $5$-vertex tournaments, with tournaments $A$ and $B$ being equivalent if $\alpha(A)=B$ for some $\alpha \in S_5$.  The equivalence classes are called *isomorphism classes* or *orbits*.  **The number of non-isomorphic tournaments, is the number of orbits**.

[Burnside's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma) gives a formula the number of orbits under a group action.  However, to use it, we need to find a way of counting the number of tournaments $T$ that are "fixed" by each $\alpha \in S_5$.

- If $\alpha(T)=T$, then $\alpha$ is said to be an *[automorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism)* of $T$.  (Alternatively, we can say that $\alpha$ *stabilises* $T$.)  This is our notion of "fixed".

Thus, to use Burnside's Lemma, for each $\alpha \in S_5$, we need to find the size of $$F_\alpha:=\{T \in \mathcal{A}:\alpha(T)=T\}$$ which gives the number of orbits (the number of non-isomorphic tournaments) as: $$\frac{1}{|S_5|} \sum_{\alpha \in S_5} |F_\alpha|.$$

This might sound horrid (since $|S_5|=120$), but it's made much easier by the observation that $|F_\alpha|$ varies only with the cycle structure of $\alpha$.

The possible cycle structures are:

- (1,1,1,1,1),
- (2,1,1,1),
- (2,2,1),
- (3,1,1),
- (3,2),
- (4,1),
- (5).

For each of these cycle structures, e.g. (2,2,1), we can pick a representative, e.g. $\beta=(12)(34)(5)$, and find $|F_\beta|$.

- *Hint*: The number of permutations with a given cycle structure is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37860), for example.
- *Hint*: Automorphisms of tournaments must have odd order.  (Why?)  This means we need only consider the cycle structures $(1,1,1,1,1)$, $(3,1,1)$ and $(5)$.

Thus, the question is really asking for $|F_{(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)}|=1024$, $|F_{(123)(4)(5)}|$ and $|F_{(12345)}|$.